# TypeScript filter array matching regex expression

Tags: arrays, regex, angular, typescript, filter

I am trying to filter an array based on a set of regex expression.If the item in the array matches any of the regex expression,I want o push it to a different array.I read that I can use match() and test() to do this but I'm unable to underetand how to do so.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Here are my regex exp:

```
RAM-HEXA-*F-Q1
RAM-D-AT44-*-Q2
RAM-D-AT44-*-Q3
```

My test Arr:

```
testData={
[
        { value: 'RAM-HEXA-34F-Q1
' },
        { value: 'RAM-D-AT44-AQ-Q2
' },
        { value: 'RAM-D-AT44-ZS-Q3
' },
        { value: 'RAM-D-N7-9-Q3
' },
       { value: 'RAM-QUATRA-1F-Q1
' },
        { value: 'RAM-X-AT44-T-Q2
' }
      ]
}
```

SO basically I am trying to get the items from testData that match the reg expresions. So I am trying to get a resulting array that looks like this:

```
filteredData={
[
        { value: 'RAM-HEXA-34F-Q1
' },
        { value: 'RAM-D-AT44-AQ-Q2
' },
        { value: 'RAM-D-AT44-ZS-Q3
' }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to test it. Be aware that non of your regexes match your data, hence the empty array result.

```js
const regexes = [
  'RAM-HEXA-*F-Q1',
  'RAM-D-AT44-*-Q2',
  'RAM-D-AT44-*-Q3',
];

const data = [
  { value: 'RAM-HEXA-34F-Q1' },
  { value: 'RAM-D-AT44-AQ-Q2' },
  { value: 'RAM-D-AT44-ZS-Q3' },
  { value: 'RAM-D-N7-9-Q3' },
  { value: 'RAM-QUATRA-1F-Q1' },
  { value: 'RAM-X-AT44-T-Q2' }
];

const filtered = data.filter(item => regexes.some(regex => item.value.match(regex)));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I'm getting error Type 'RegExpMatchArray' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Comment: Also RAM-HEXA-34F-Q1,RAM-D-AT44-AQ-Q2 and RAM-D-AT44-ZS-Q3 should match.The * in regex indicates that any character can be there.

Comment: @rock11 I have made valid data and you didn't. Cope with your model and it should work. And no, your regexes aren't correctly written. `*` means that the caracter it follows can appear 0 to N times, it doesn't mean that it matches any character. That's how SQL works, not how regexes do.

Comment: I want to match any character.Can you tell me what to change to accomplish that.I'm new to this

Comment: any character once would be `.`. For several multiple characters, use `.*`. For at least one character, use `.+`

Comment: Worked.But I'm getting Type 'RegExpMatchArray' is not assignable to type 'boolean' error in vs code.

Comment: @rock11 `I have made valid data and you didn't. Cope with your model and it should work.`.

Comment: I am using the data model that you've given in example.

Comment: @rock11 And if you run the example, you'll see that it works. This means you did something else on your hand.

Comment: It is working.I can see the result in console.But I'm still getting that error.I am doing exactly what you've suggested.

Comment: I think it may be due to regexes.some();

Comment: @rock11 oh you meant a typing error ! Simply use `!!item.value.match`, that parses the value to a boolean.

Comment: @rock11 not a good solution beause it makes you loose the intellisense on your array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter array method:

```
var regex1 = RegExp('RAM-HEXA-*(F-Q1)?');
var filtered = testData.filter((x) = > 
{
return regex1.test(x.value);
})
```

The same with other conditions.

That it is example in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3dgvw7yh/

Comment: Getting error Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type

Comment: I forgot add value property.

Comment: I have adjusted your regular expression it was not correct